# Nodejs express mime type issues

Tags: node.js, express, mime-types

My css files are served as html/text instead of as stylesheet. Resulting in the css does not work. Heres the error message:

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3030/css/bootstrap.css".

And here's my server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
  stylus = require('stylus'),
  logger = require('morgan'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  path = require('path');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();

function compile(str, path){
  return stylus(str).set('filename', path);
}

app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(stylus.middleware(
  {
      src: __dirname + '/public',
      compile: compile
  }
));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
});

var port = 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '...');
```

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score -1):

Try this- If you are using nodemon change to http-server https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: Hi I am using nodemon. I have installed http-server now, how do I run it? 

http-server server.js ??

Comment: You can find different tutorials online or follow this - http://blog.modulus.io/build-your-first-http-server-in-nodejs